# Would TcpClient re-transmit packet if no ack was received?

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

I am wondering if TcpClient would retransmit the packet if anything happened to it and never got received or the ack never came back to the client? I am thinking about doing the following but I am not sure if it will be useless or not?

```
if(data.length != reply.length){
    NetworkStream str = client.GetStream();
    str.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if TcpClient would retransmit the packet if anything happened to it

Understand that this question needs to have a two part answer.

1. TcpClient is not responsible to retransmit packets, so the direct answer is no.
2. Will the packet be re-transmitted under certain circumstances that resulted in the packet not reaching the destination or being corrupted while reaching the destination; yes, as this is the job of the TCP stack (usually the Operating System, not TcpClient in this instance).